# What's the purpose of the files created at activator auto-update?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

Typesafe Activator has just updated itself to version 1.2.12 (from 1.2.10), although I have no idea currently where it installed itself.

It created some files in my project.  Here is a list:

```
activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-idea-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-eclipse-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt
```

Can I safely delete them all? What is their purpose? Will the Activator browser app still work without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While updating itself, activator copies the jars to `~/.ivy2/cache` (under `com.typesafe.activator`, `org.scala-sbt` amongst the others) and `~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.11.1` (since the 1.2.12 version uses it).

```
Getting Scala 2.11.1 (for activator-launcher)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    6 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24060kB/96ms)
```

I remember the files under `project`, but can't reproduce how to create them while activator updates itself so I'm not 100% sure what's inside.

I'm pretty sure you can remove `project/activator-sbt-idea-shim.sbt` and `project/activator-sbt-eclipse-shim.sbt`, but uncertain about `project/activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt` (probably yes).

Comment: It's safe to remove all those shim files; activator will re-add them as needed (when the UI starts up). It does take longer to start up the UI if they aren't there since it has to reboot sbt after adding them. These files are just adding sbt plugins that activator makes use of from the UI, such as sbt eclipse plugin, etc.

Comment: the updating btw uses the same mechanism as setting sbt.version in project/build.properties, only in this case it picks the activator version instead of sbt version and stores it in ~/.activator/version-0.properties